# pylint complains about empty __init__.py

Tags: python, python-2.7, pylint

I get this weird error:

```
$ epylint .
*************
 mysubdir/__init__.py:1: fatal (F0010, parse-error, ) error while code parsing: Unable to load file 'mysubdir/__init__.py' ([Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mysubdir/__init__.py')
```

Note that `mysubdir/__init__.py` *does* exist and contains a single empty line.

Note that

```
$ epylint mysubdir
```

works just fine and produces no messages.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're running pylint in your workdir (`pylint .`). Pylint will expect an **init**.py file there.

Take a look at [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48024049/pylint-raises-error-if-directory-doesnt-contain-init-py-file).

Your best shot is to select the directories you want to lint. If you can't do so (ie: Django project). You'll have to make a custom workaround like in the thread.