# pylint raises error if directory doesn't contain __init__.py file

Tags: python-3.x, pylint

I have the folder that contains only python scripts for execution. It's not necessary to keep `__init__.py` file. So can I ignore such error?

```
$ pylint /app
Using config file /app/pylintrc
************* 
F:  1, 0: error while code parsing: Unable to load file /app/__init__.py:
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/__init__.py' (parse-error)
```

Comment: pylint checks scripts, not directories.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```bash
$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.13.6
BuildVersion:   17G65

$ pylint --version
pylint 2.1.1
astroid 2.0.3
Python 3.7.0 (default, Jul 23 2018, 20:22:55) 
[Clang 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)]
```

## Update

I got this to work by trying:

```
$ cd /app
$ pylint *.py
```

or try:

```
$ pylint /path/to/app/*.py
```

and got the whole thing working.

```
...
Report
======
************* Module <yourmodname>
...
X statements analysed.

Statistics by type
------------------

+---------+-------+-----------+-----------+------------+---------+
|type     |number |old number |difference |%documented |%badname |
+=========+=======+===========+===========+============+=========+
...
```

## Error

I had tried to do:

```
$ pylint .
************* Module .
__init__.py:1:0: F0010: error while code parsing: Unable to load file 
__init__.py:
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '__init__.py' (parse-error)
```

Comment: Just to add to @JayRizzo 's reply, if you would like to run pylint on python files only, use

`$ pylint /path/to/folder/*.py`

If you do not use that, it will run on all the files in the directory (e.g: README.md). You would not want to run pylint on non-python files.

Comment: Yes you are correct @Darshak .  I forgot to add that. I will update when I get home later.

Comment: How do do this when the input command is: ```pylint --output-format=text . | tee ./pylint/pylint.log || pylint-exit $?``` ?

Comment: @VincentBénet try this `pylint --output-format=text *.py | tee ./pylint/pylint.log || pylint-exit $`

Comment: A command that seemingly even better: `find api/python/cli -name "*.py" | xargs pylint`. This way it will work if python files are located across a directories hierarchy.

Answer (score 12):

This is a known open issue of PyLint:

[lint all files in a directory](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/352) **(open)**

[Consider supporting a folder of python files which is not a package](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/512) **(duplicate, closed)**

Unfortunately, as we can see in the discussion, no one continued working on it.

**UPD:**

Resolved in Pylint 2.13.5, released on 2022-04-06. Use the `--recursive` option to activate the new feature.

Comment: Now resolved in Pylint 2.13.5, released on 2022-04-06. Use the `--recursive` option to activate the new feature.

Answer (score 6):

This issue appeared in some projects of ours.

In one of these projects, we had a very recent successful build, but suddenly everything started to fail with no reason. We went to our CI logs to the last successful build, copied the exact version of everything installed. When building that way, everything worked. New versions would fail.

The successful build on this project was from **23.02.2019** and the failing one from **25.02.2019**. No substantial changes introduced. Running with the same state as before, failure again...

A couple more hours were invested into this and we found:

- while debugging, other errors started to happen. It turns out that `astroid` [released](https://github.com/PyCQA/astroid/releases) version **2.2.0** in **27.02.2019** and this basically broke `pylint`. Pinning `astroid` back to version **2.1.0** solves this problem. We'll keep it like this until they release a patch or `pylint` starts to deal with the new version. There's an [issue](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/pull/2774) on Github about this.
- with the `astroid` problem addressed, we got back to the failures due to the lack of `__init__.py` files in some directories (these are Python 3.7 projects and we don't need empty `__init__.py` files...)
- several attempts were done to find why the old combination worked and the new one didn't. After a lot of failing builds, we found that a **PATCH** [update](https://github.com/timothycrosley/isort/releases) of another dependency of `pylint` -- `isort` -- from **4.3.4** to **4.3.5**, released in **25.02.2019**, introduced the bug. Pinning it back to version 4.3.4 worked just fine. Anything above it fails. Honestly, that update didn't follow the rules of semantic versioning (it's definitely *NOT* a patch release... It's more likely a *MAJOR*!).

Why exactly `isort` is causing this, I couldn't find yet, but I decided to share these findings here, so you can save several hours of trial & error.

**TL;DR**:

Add this to your `requirements.txt` (at least until the next release of `pylint`):

```
# astroid 2.2.0 seems to break everything in pylint
astroid==2.1.0
# isort above 4.3.4 introduces the "__init__.py not found" issue
isort==4.3.4
```

Comment: It looks like, we need to downgrade pylint as well? 
Because it errors out this message: ERROR: pylint 2.5.2 has requirement astroid<=2.5,>=2.4.0, but you'll have astroid 2.1.0 which is incompatible.

Comment: I'm not sure. I don't remember having problems recently with `pylint`. I think the current set of packages is compatible, when you use the most up-to-date version

Answer (score 4):

The [--recursive](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/configuration/all-options.html#recursive) option worked for me to run pylint (version 2.15.3) for all python files in directory "test":

```
pylint test --recursive=true
```

Comment: `pylint: error: no such option: --recursive`
pylint 2.8.2

Comment: The option has been added in version 2.13: https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/whatsnew/2/2.13/summary.html#other-changes

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution (will not work on Windows):

```
pylint $(echo -n /app/*.py && echo -n ' ' && find /app -type d -maxdepth 1 -exec test -e '{}'/__init__.py \; -print | grep -v '^/app/\.')
```

So this will include as arguments all the `.py` files in the `/app` directory and all the directories in the `/app` directory containing a `__init__.py` file at their root. The grep piping is removing all the directory names in `/app` starting by a dot.